# Validating data from an API without repeating try blocks

Tags: python

I'm getting data from an API, and I want to validate if the data from it is there so i can use it without breaking the script. Currently I'm doing this with `try` blocks for each value. I'm wondering if there is a better way of writing this with DRY principles in mind.

```py
 for record in event['data']:   
    try:
        name = record['entityDetail']['companySummary']['name']
        nameObj = {
                'name': 'name',
                'value': name,
                'type': 'S',   
            }
        objExpression.append(nameObj)
    except Exception as e:
        error = 'Company Id:'+ id + ' property ' + str(e) + ' is not defined!'
        print(error)
    try:
        brandCode = record['entityDetail']['companySummary']['brandCode']
        brandCodeObj = {
                'name': 'brandCode',
                'value': brandCode,
                'type': 'S',   
            }
        objExpression.append(brandCodeObj)
    except Exception as e:
        error = 'Company Id:'+ id + ' property ' + str(e) + ' is not defined!'
        print(error)
...
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: if you feel that you are repeating your self, an easy solution (that is also often the right one) is to put the code in a function.

Comment: Just a minor thing, but looks like you could use some [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) - string concatenation(using +) runs slower and requires more effort!

Answer (score 1):

**You could use a nested `for` loop** to repeat the logic for each field you want to add. You could use a helper function, but you'd need to pass a lot of parameters in, plus it would likely need to have the side effect of appending to a list, so I would say it's not worth it.

**If you're just trying to get rid of the `try` blocks, you can use chained `.get()` calls instead.** If any of the properties that you try to access don't exist, `name` will be assigned to `None`, which you can then check using an `if` statement.

The second parameter defines what to return in case the key doesn't exist. In this case, we return an empty dictionary, so that the remaining `.get()` calls can perform indexing without throwing an error. (`.get()` without a second parameter returns `None` if the corresponding key doesn't exist, hence why it's omitted for the last call in the chain.)

Here's a code snippet that implements both of these changes:

```py
for record in event['data']:
    for field_name in ['name', 'brandCode']:   
        field_data = record.get('entityDetail', {}).get('companySummary', {}).get(field_name)
        
        if field_data:
            field_obj = {
                    'name': field_name,
                    'value': field_data,
                    'type': 'S',   
                }
            objExpression.append(field_obj)
        else:
            print("Could not fetch name!")
```